# classs name in UiDevice.dumpWindowHierarchy() is not as same as it's name in layout xml

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

Why ui components's name in the file created by the function UiDevice.dumpWindowHiearchy() are generally not as same as thier original names defined in layout.xml and source code?
What have happened before the window's root object was created?Here are tow examples.

[class name in the file dumpeded by uiautomator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUrdi.png)

[class name in activity's layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G88TA.png)

Comment: It looks like that method uses the Accessibility framework to traverse the hierarchy, and the report is showing the `getAccessibilityClassName()` return for each node. For `AppCompatSeekbar`, the last class in its inheritance chain to override that method is `android.widget.Seekbar`, and similarly for `SwitchCompat`, which makes sense from an Accessibility standpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer sincerely.@Mike M.